# Inserting an image inserts extra bracketed numbers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing

I don't know if this is a bug or what so I'm reporting it as a bug.

1. Insert an image using: [image]
2. Then see what seems to be an extra pair of brackets wrapped around a "1":[image]
3. This doesn't seem to affect rendering at this point: [image]

Is this duplicated bracketed number in the image links intentional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design and is a recent change.

The syntax you see inserts the image *and* creates a link to the image. This way images that are larger than the column for posts can be scaled down in the post but the full version of the image is easily gotten to.

The syntax to do that has been around for a long time, it's just that the image button was recently changed to work that way.

See [this answer to "Support showing image in original size in overlay"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151793/support-showing-image-in-original-size-in-overlay/261182#261182).

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151793/support-showing-image-in-original-size-in-overlay/261182#261182 I see that the images that lack the extra layer of brackets do not themselves open up into a new window.